# Can't convert a tf.data.Dataset object to a numpy iterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using Tensorflow 1.14.0 and tensorflow_datasets 1.2.0

When trying to run the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

smallnorb = tfds.load("smallnorb")
smallnorb_train, smallnorb_test = smallnorb["train"], smallnorb["test"]
assert isinstance(smallnorb_train, tf.data.Dataset)
smallnorb_train = smallnorb_train.as_numpy_iterator()
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'as_numpy_iterator'
```

According to the [tensorflow_datasets docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#as_numpy_iterator) this should work.

Why won't it? And why am I getting a DatasetV1Adapter object in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_datasets` versions.

**Please use `2.x` unless you need `1.x` for some very specific reasons.**

This code works if you use `tensorflow 2.1.0` and `tensorflow_datasets 2.0.0`. Proper documentation for `1.x` of `tf.data.Dataset` can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and it has no such method indeed.

Answer (score 1):

As @szymon mentioned, tensorflow-1.14 does not support the `as_numpy_iterator`. You should move your code to `tf>=2.0`

A handy tip which I frequently use is firing up a REPL python shell in one of the bash shells and use `dir(tf.data.Dataset)` to list all the attributes & methods that can be called from that object. You can further use the `help(tf.data.Dataset.xxx)` for parameters and return values of that method.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> dir(tf.data.Dataset) 
... <output>

>>> help(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
... and so on
```

If you do the same, you'll find that `as_numpy_iterator` won't be present in the `dir(tf.data.Dataset)` list output, hence the error.